# ALSA "dmix plugin supports only playback stream" error when using dmix on beagleboard

Tags: audio, alsa, embedded-linux, beagleboard

On a Beagleboard, I need it to play sound from several processes.

The default /etc/asound.conf is empty, so I put [this dmix example](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#dmix) in.

Now sund mixes fine, but when I'm trying to run a process that uses a microphone, I'm getting `"(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream"`.

What do I fix in the configuration to make software mixing and microphone work?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - I don't need to mix a microphone signal, I only want it to work. Currently, it doesn't, at least for some programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CL` answer (while not being too verbose and not providing example) is right; if you want to also use microphone while using `dmix`, you need to use `asym` too.

Example configuration allowing both `dmix` and microphone access might [look like this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic.php?p=958187):

```
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 8192
   rate 44100
    }

    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.asymed {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "dmixer"
        capture.pcm "hw:0,0"
}



pcm.dsp0 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "asymed"
}

pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "asymed"
}

pcm.default {
   type plug
   slave.pcm "asymed"
}

ctl.mixer0 {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

or whatever your configuration is, you want your `default` not be to `dmixer` but `asym` (and have that `pcm.asymed` block with defines separate `playback` [your old `dmixer` and `capture` devices)

Comment: Thanks. Can no longer test, but accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The `dmix` plugin works only for playback devices.

To be able to have a device that uses `dmix` for playback and does something else for capturing, you have to use the [asym plugin](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Asym) to define different plugins for playback/capture.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I wasn't clear - I don't need to mix a microphone signal, I only want it to work. Currently, it doesn't, at least for some programs.